# C++: how to pass an object to another object constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

I know this question is asked a lot, but I come from Java and I haven't done any C/C++ for a very long time.

Can you please remind me how to correctly pass an object to another object's constructor in C++?

For example, I need to pass a new Light object to the Button constructor:

```
// LED Light
class Light {
    int pin;

    public:
        Light(int p) {
            pin = p;
        }
};

// BUTTON
class Button {
    Light ledLight;

    public:
        Button(Light l) {
            ledLight = l;
        }

};

Light my_led(0);

Button my_button(my_led);
```

This is how I would do it in a Java-like fasion.
However this produces the following error:

```
::  In constructor ‘Button::Button(Light)’:
::  16:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘Light::Light()’
::  16:19: note: candidates are:
::  6:3: note: Light::Light(int)
::  6:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
::  2:7: note: Light::Light(const Light&)
::  2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Is the object being passed by reference or is it attempting to create a new one when I create a new Button?

Or do I need to declare the Light as a pointer in the Button's constructor?

Any help is much apreciated!

Comment: Now write 100 times: "C is **not** C++ is **not** C!"

Comment: It's also worth noting that unlike Java, changes made to `my_button.ledLight` will not change the contents of `my_led`. You copied the object.

Comment: @Olaf, I am really sorry and especially ashamed since I myself often ask people to do the same thing with 'Java/JavaScript'. Thanks for the edit.


@BillLynch, how would I pass `my_led` directly to `my_button`? So that changes from the button affect its contents.

Comment: @YemSalat You can make `ledlight` a reference

Comment: @awesomeyi, like so?
`Light& ledLight;` and then: `Button(Light& l) { }` in the constructor declaration?

Comment: @YemSalat: If you want to do that then, from what I can tell, you also want to store a reference. That means the member variable will be a `Light&`, not a `Light`. I would suggest you don't do this though. The ownership and lifetime rules won't be clear and your code will be bug-prone.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, its really hard transitioning from Java to C++. What is the proper way of achieving this (passing an object to constructor by reference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a default constructor.  Try modifying your class like this:

```
class Light {
    int pin;

    public:
        Light()=default;  //<-- put this in
        Light(int p) {
            pin = p;
        }
};
```

As to why you're not automatically generating a default constructor, it's because you're already declaring a constructor of some type, so the compiler won't generate a default one (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor, see sections on implicitly declared/defined constructors).

---

In response to the comment:

> Wouldn't it attempt to call the default constructor instead of the one
>   which passes the arguments?

When your executing code gets to the last line:

```
Button my_button(my_led);
```

You're instantiating a `Button` and a `Light` as part of the `Button` instantiation process.  Without specifying a default `Light::Light()` constructor, you're leaving out instructions on how to instantiate a `Light` object without a value, which you need to do before copying the value of `my_led` into my_button.  You'll get the results you intended, you're just currently leaving out instructions to the compiler on how to perform an intermediate step, i.e. instantiate `Light` without any arguments.

---

Some things to think about:

What are you *really* trying to do?  Just by looking at your instruction code:

```
Light my_led(0);

Button my_button(my_led);
```

It seems to me like you're trying to say "a light named `my_led` exists" and "a button named `my_button` exists and needs `my_led`".  Do you want the button to refer to a specific LED that exists already, or just an LED that has the same values?

If you think you'll want to refer to the actual LED from that button then you might want to consider doing the following:

```
class Button {
    const Light *ledLight;

    public:
        Button(const Light& l) : 
            ledLight{&l}
        {}
};
```

That way, your `Button` has a pointer to the `Light` you created, and whatever you do with the `Light` inside your `Button` code will be performed on the `Light` object you already instantiated, instead of some separate copy of `Light` you create by copy-constructing `Light` with your current `Button` constructor.

If you want the button to actually modify the light, revise `Button` like so:

```
class Button {
    // constant reference to changeable object
    Light *  const ledLight; 

    public:
        /**
         * You're providing a reference to a light that can be changed 
         * (i.e. button code can toggle lit status or something)
         */
        Button(Light & l) : 
            ledLight{&l}
        {}
};
```

The above you could think of as having an unchanging wire from the button to the LED.  If you think you'll be reassigning the LED that gets lit from the button, you'd take out the `const` keyword from the pointer member in `Button` as well.

Comment: Wouldn't it attempt to call the default constructor instead of the one which passes the arguments?

Comment: If you explicitly define constructor, the default one won't be automatically created

Comment: @YemSalat When you do `Button my_button(my_led);`, you're already calling the default `Light::Light()` constructor to first instantiate the `Light` member when instantiating `Button`.  Then you copy the value of `Light` provided in the `Button::Button(Light)` constructor.

Comment: @TJOlaes thanks heaps for the explanation! You are exactly right of what I am trying to do, and each button needs to have control over actual LEDs.

However, when I run your code for the Button class I get the following error:
`In constructor ‘Button::Button(const Light&)’:`
`error: cannot convert ‘const Light’ to ‘const Light*’ in assignment`

In this way do I still pass it to constructor with: `Button my_button(my_led);` i.e. will it automatially know that this is a reference to the object and it doesn't need to be copied?

Comment: My bad, I had left in some copied text in my suggested revision.  I revised it accordingly.  The idea is that you're passing a read-only reference of the light to the button.  If you want the button to modify the light somehow (like change its status to "lit" or something), you'll want to leave out the `const` keywords.

Comment: @TJOlaes oh, OK. thanks! It is working now. So this way I don't need to assign the `ledLight` variable again in the constructor body? (PS sorry, I edited my previous comment while you were typing, can you please answer that as well. Basically I need to know if doing it this way will only create 1 object in memory and it will presist as long as I don't explicitly remove it)

Comment: Correct, you do not have to assign the ledLight variable again in the constructor body, since I used initializer lists.  Initializer lists are *only for constructors*.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list for more information.

Comment: @TJOlaes sorry I am still having troubles with this.
I am trying to put my LEDs into an array and pass the reference from this array to the new buttons. Like so: `Light all_lights[] = {my_led1, my_led2};` `Button my_button1(845, all_lights[0]);` - it now seems like the Button no longer has control of the same LED ??

Comment: Sorry, I mean  it now seems like its creating two instances of each LED ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84925/discussion-between-tj-olaes-and-yemsalat).

Answer (score 7):

The program tries to initiate `ledLight` using the default constructor and then assigns `l` to `ledLight`. The compiler gives you an error because there is no default constructor for `Light`. Try this instead:

```
Button(Light l): ledLight(l) { }
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the correct syntax if I have more parameters, for example: `Button(int pin, long time, Light l)` ?

Comment: @YemSalat You can try `Button(int pin, long time, Light l): b_pin(pin), b_time(time), ledLight(l) {}`

Comment: Also, remember when you construct objects this way, they will be destroyed at the end of block (function, loop, if-clause, whatever). If you expect your Light object to live longer, you have to use `new Light(0)` and pass it as a pointer to Button (preferably shared pointer).

Comment: But wouldn't just re-writing it as `Button(Light& l): ledLight(l) { }` do the trick? Do I still need to change the way I pass it to the constructor?

Comment: @MaciejDziuban: That is not true, at all. The `Light` will be copied for storage. Your suggestion of dynamic allocation is going in the wrong direction.